# invalid Json error when trying to use the reference function in Azure ARM to create firewall rules based on resource property

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am creating azure firewall DNAT rules as part of an azure devops pipeline.  I dont want to specify the public IP manually, i want to pull this value from the properties of the public nic.  This way if we clone the pipeline, or rebuild, we dont have to update the IP address.

This is just an excerpt from the ARM template.  This first example works.

```
"destinationAddresses": [
            "52.180.91.89"
]
```

My attempt to replace it is below.  Please note that the public IP is created in the ARM template so I am not referencing the full path to the resource.

```
"destinationAddresses": "[reference(variables('arm_firewall_buildagentip')).ipAddress]"
```

The error i am receiving is below.  Its returning the correct value, but I am not sure how to format it so it can be accepted in the firewall rule.

```
##[error]BadRequest: {
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequestFormat",
    "message": "Cannot parse the request.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InvalidJson",
        "message": "Error converting value \"52.180.91.89\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. Path 'properties.natRuleCollections[0].properties.rules[1].destinationAddresses', line 1, position 2880."
      }
    ]
  }
} undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 options, convert it to [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#array):

```
"[array(reference(variables('arm_firewall_buildagentip')).ipAddress)]"
```

or you can use the property that accepts [a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/2018-11-01/networksecuritygroups/securityrules):

```
"destinationAddressPrefix": "[reference(variables('arm_firewall_buildagentip')).ipAddress]"
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  Using the array option got me working.  i dont believe option 2 would work as this was for the Firewall and not the NSG and the firewall doesnt have destinationAddressPrefix.  destinationAddresses is already a string.

Comment: oh, okay, sorry, its me failing to read ;) in the case it helped you - consider accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I hit this when trying to set connection strings using the "Azure App Service Settings" task.

My JSON was:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Global",
    "value": "$(ConnectionStrings.Global)",
    "type": "SQLServer",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]

this is valid json but the actual connection string was something like:

    "Server=my.dbserver.com\db;Database=mytestdb;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;"

The problem is when the place holder $(ConnectionStrings.Global) is replaced the single back slash in the connection string causes the JSON to be invalid and it needs double escaping.
```